# Accessing files on the XP partition from Windows 7RC

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs

Like every self respecting geek out there I wanted to give the Windows 7RC a try, so here am I with a dual boot system...

- Good old XP for everyday use
- Windows 7Rc

Booting into the RC I thought of copying some files from my user profile folder on the XP side right into RC side, but it looks like this is not possible because the files are owned by an unknown user-id (my alter ego on the XP side, I'd say). Not even running Windows Explorer in administrator mode works.

Is there a way to "mount" the XP partition in some kind of "ignore permissions" mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less destructive way to do it is to reboot into XP and grant "Everyone" or "Users" the permissions to read, but not to write, the files. Then reboot into W7 and copy over the files. This avoids having to take ownership of any files from any OS, and leaves the original permissions (largely) untouched.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take ownership of the files/folder and then give your w7 account permission to read them as well - they're currently exclusively accessable by the XP user as it's a user profile... or, under XP, change the current permissions that only gives your XP user access - to allow "Users" read rights as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, the problem you have is because permissions that have been set are from the XP partition, and Windows 7 does not recognise the SID's for these users. To get around this on 7 you could take ownership of the folder and add your windows 7 account into the permissions list, this should then give you access. The next time you boot into XP, you could take backup ownership of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can modify User Profiles folder permitions on XP drive to add Win7 Administrators access to it. User folders should inherit it from upper level